# What's the most common word to refer to a soccer team's shield (or coat of arms)?

Tags: sports

I am trying to find the most common way to refer to a soccer team's shield (or coat of arms).

Comment: Let me add somthing here, Shield, Coat of Arms, Logo or whatever they are probably all correct. But i want to know what is the most common one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the websites and wikipedia pages of half a dozen football teams, **badge** seems to be the most popular term, followed by **crest** and **logo**.

This seems like a question for which [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Arsenal+badge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) should be perfect; but oddly, looking for phrases like `Arsenal badge` there, I haven’t managed to find *any* hits for any combination, although Googling shows that they are used plenty often in the wild.  I suppose there just can’t have been many sports texts in the corpora that Ngrams is based on.

Comment: Definitely **badge** - a player kisses the badge to show their love for the team.

Answer (score 5):

Another word I would use in this context is **emblem.**

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **logo** (an identifying symbol, often for use in advertising) or **insignia** (a distinguishing mark or sign)...?

Sample usage:

> I've got a towel with Manchester U's logo on it, because I love being able to wipe the floor with them.

Edit to add:
I would guess that "logo" is the most commonly used term since it is advertising-oriented and most of the time I'd expect that their mark is being referred to in an advertising-related way (selling towels or shirts or other marketing materials, for example).

Answer (score 2):

**Crest**?

> *Heraldry* A distinctive device borne above the shield of a coat of arms ... or separately reproduced ... to represent a family or corporate body.